# django view model iteration

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

Model:

```
class Subject(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    places = models.IntegerField()

class Temp(models.Model):
    subject_r = models.ForeignKey(Subject)
```

Now in my views I want to do simple thing:
If Subject id exists in Temp table, field places (which is integer) need to be decremented by 1, else, it should stay as it is, and then I want to display the correct places variable in my template. Note that i don't want to save new value in a database, i just want it to be displayed correctly in a template.

Comment: Do you care about the number of times the subject id is present in the Temp table? If so then use count(). Maybe something like this in your view: Temp.objects.filter(subject_r = self.id).count()

Comment: self.id should be subject.id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
temp = Temp.objects.values_list('subject_r_id', flat=True)
subjects = Subject.objects.all()
for subject in subjects:
    if subject.id in temp:
        subject.places = subject.places - 1
```

Since it's for display only, I would actually set an arbitrary new attribute so that it's clear you're not trying to modify the database.

```
temp = Temp.objects.values_list('subject_r_id', flat=True)
subjects = Subject.objects.all()
for subject in subjects:
    if subject.id in temp:
        subject.places_display = subject.places - 1
    else:
        subject.places_display = subject.places


{{ subject.places_display }}
```

Comment: How can I display in template all subjects now ? I don't know how to pass it as a context so i can iterate subjects with normal, and decremented values

Comment: In the same way you'd pass any other data to the template context.